# Waiting for each animation in loop to finish before running the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm looking to run a delay on the count up function, so whenever the finish class name of counter finishes it will then run the count up whenever the previous one has finished etc.

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
        countNum: countTo
    },
    {
        duration: 4000,
        easing:'linear',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I only see one loop here, where is the second one you want to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working with an `each` loop. You have to use the `complete` callback an do it by your own, because the animation is asynchron.

I would use a recursive, self-execution function. Pretty easy, just start the next one when completed.

```
var elements = $('.counter');
var current = 0;

(function next() {
    var $this = elements.eq(current),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({countNum: countTo}, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);

            if( (++current) < elements.length ) {
                next();
            }
        }
    });  
})();
```

Comment: My bad for getting mixed up on the title - thanks for clarifying and answering question.